# template literals not working in atom.io

Tags: template-literals

I am following along on a javascript tutorial about template literals.
I have followed the instructors code exactly, but I cannot get the same           output he did. (and yes, I am using backtics)

```
let name = 'bob'; 
console.log(`hi $(name)`);

Instructor Output: hi bob
My Output: hi $(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curly brackets

```
let name = 'bob'; 
console.log(`hi ${name}`);
```

And it would output `hi bob`

For detailed documentation see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals